# Windowsphone 8.1 webview open phone application

Tags: webview, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

In my application I have a Page that loads a WebView. 
Sometimes I receive Url that causes the opening of another application such as Phone\Sms\Store\etc. I'm trying to find a way to detect such scenario that my Page moves to the background due to such Url.

Does anyone have an idea?
Thx

Comment: Can you maybe add more detail to your question, I went out on a hunch in answering the question. But I think with more detail I may be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 options to try and figure out where or what your WebView is doing:

- [NavigationStarting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigationstarting)
- [ContentLoading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.contentloading)
- [DOMContentLoaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.domcontentloaded)
- [NavigationCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigationcompleted)

Looking at the documentation it seems as if the best way is in `NavigationStarting`
event and setting the [WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs.Cancel property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webviewnavigationstartingeventargs.cancel) to `true`

```
<WebView NavigationStarting="webView1_NavigationStarting" />
```

C#

We can use a `Dictionary<string, bool>` to store and check whether the webpage we are going to is a valid webpage

```
private Dictionary<string, bool> knownWebSites;
void webView1_NavigationStarting(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
{
    string url = "";
    try { 
        url = args.Uri.ToString();
        if(knownWebSites.ContainsKey[url])
        {
             if(knownWebSites[url] == flase)
             {
                 args.Cancel = true;
             }
             // contine this is a known webpage without issues
        }
        else
        {
             args.Cancel = true;
             CheckHttpWebpage(url); // first inspect the page
        }
    }
    finally
    {
       // Do stuff
    }
}

async void CheckHttpWebpage(string url)
{
     HttpClientResponse response = await HttpGet(url); // this is a custom http get function
     if( IsValidResponse(response))
     {
         knownWebSites.Add(url, false); // this page has issues
     }
     else
     {
         knownWebSites.Add(url, true); // this page is good
         webview.Navigate(new Uri(url));
     }
}

bool IsValidResponse(HttpClientResponse response)
{
   // In here you can examine 
   // 1. response content to make sure it does not return phone numbers, and you have it, so you can do something pretty with it now :-)
   // 2. url to make sure it isn't a redirect
   // 3. lots of other stuff to ensure that the navigating to webpage is valid
}
```

It is recommended to use `HttpWebResponse` if authorization is needed for the webpages.

Comment: Hi, i'm afraid it won't work, the final Url i'm targeting could lead to Win. store and then the WebView automatically opens the store without notifying me. The event of completed will arrive but without the redirect to the Store or any other 3rd party application such as Phone\SMS\Email.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed answer, i'm already using the NavigationStarting event but the issue is that the server response is a redirect to, for instance, tel:+17337373883 and the OS automatically opens the tel. Application without any option from my side to do something. Just to be more specific, on the Sniffer trace i can see the server response is 302 (Redirect) and not 200 (HttpOk) and in the response the Location element is the tel:+17337373883.

Comment: Updated again, but this time it was a fun answer :-) yay! +1 Q for fun :D